# Problems with YUM/Scientifix Linux 6.3 (inconsistent rpm database?..)

Tags: yum, rpm, scientific-linux

Recently I saw this:

```
[root@NOTEBOOK /etc/yum.repos.d] yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                        |  17 kB     00:00     
 * epel: mirror.pmf.kg.ac.rs
 * rpmforge: ftp.lug.ro
 * sl: ftp.scientificlinux.org
 * sl-security: ftp.scientificlinux.org
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package wine.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: wine-openal(x86-64) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-openal(x86-32) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package wine-capi.i686 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-capi.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-capi.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-capi.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-cms.i686 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-cms.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-cms.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-cms.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-common.noarch 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-common.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-core.i686 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-core.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-core.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 for package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgstbase-0.10.so.0 for package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgstapp-0.10.so.0 for package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686
---> Package wine-core.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-courier-fonts.noarch 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-courier-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-desktop.noarch 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-desktop.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-fonts.noarch 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: wine-tahoma-fonts = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-fonts-1.4.1-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: wine-ms-sans-serif-fonts = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-fonts-1.4.1-1.el6.noarch
---> Package wine-ldap.i686 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-ldap.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-ldap.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-ldap.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-marlett-fonts.noarch 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-marlett-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-pulseaudio.i686 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-pulseaudio.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-pulseaudio.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: wine-alsa(x86-32) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-pulseaudio-1.4.1-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: alsa-plugins-pulseaudio(x86-32) for package: wine-pulseaudio-1.4.1-1.el6.i686
---> Package wine-pulseaudio.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: wine-alsa(x86-64) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-pulseaudio-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package wine-small-fonts.noarch 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-small-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-symbol-fonts.noarch 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-symbol-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-system-fonts.noarch 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-system-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-twain.i686 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-twain.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-twain.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-twain.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package wine-wow.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-wow.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package alsa-plugins-pulseaudio.i686 0:1.0.21-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package gstreamer.i686 0:0.10.29-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package gstreamer-plugins-base.i686 0:0.10.29-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtheoraenc.so.1(libtheoraenc_1.0) for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcdda_interface.so.0 for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: liboil-0.3.so.0 for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libtheoradec.so.1(libtheoradec_1.0) for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libvisual-0.4.so.0 for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcdda_paranoia.so.0 for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libtheoradec.so.1 for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgudev-1.0.so.0 for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libtheoraenc.so.1 for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
---> Package wine-alsa.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-alsa.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-ms-sans-serif-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-openal.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libopenal.so.1 for package: wine-openal-1.4.1-1.el6.i686
---> Package wine-openal.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libopenal.so.1()(64bit) for package: wine-openal-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package wine-tahoma-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cdparanoia-libs.i686 0:10.2-5.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libgudev1.i686 0:147-2.40.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libudev = 147-2.40.el6 for package: libgudev1-147-2.40.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libudev.so.0 for package: libgudev1-147-2.40.el6.i686
---> Package liboil.i686 0:0.3.16-4.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libtheora.i686 1:1.1.0-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package libvisual.i686 0:0.4.0-9.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-openal.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libopenal.so.1 for package: wine-openal-1.4.1-1.el6.i686
---> Package wine-openal.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libopenal.so.1()(64bit) for package: wine-openal-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libudev.i686 0:147-2.40.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-openal.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libopenal.so.1 for package: wine-openal-1.4.1-1.el6.i686
---> Package wine-openal.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libopenal.so.1()(64bit) for package: wine-openal-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: wine-openal-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
       Requires: libopenal.so.1
Error: Package: wine-openal-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: libopenal.so.1()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@NOTEBOOK /etc/yum.repos.d] yum update --skip-broken
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.pmf.kg.ac.rs
 * rpmforge: ftp.lug.ro
 * sl: ftp.scientificlinux.org
 * sl-security: ftp.scientificlinux.org
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package wine.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: wine-openal(x86-64) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-openal(x86-32) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package wine-capi.i686 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package wine-capi.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.el6 will be updated
```

...bla-bla

```
--> Processing Dependency: wine-common = 1.2.3-1.el6 for package: wine-desktop-1.2.3-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: wine-common = 1.2.3-1.el6 for package: wine-core-1.2.3-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: wine-common = 1.2.3-1.el6 for package: wine-core-1.2.3-1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Skip-broken could not solve problems
Error: Package: wine-openal-1.4.1-1.el6.i686 (epel)
       Requires: libopenal.so.1
Error: Package: wine-openal-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: libopenal.so.1()(64bit)
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@NOTEBOOK /etc/yum.repos.d] 
[root@NOTEBOOK /etc/yum.repos.d] rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@NOTEBOOK /etc/yum.repos.d]
```

..and the same starts again if I yum update..

I can't install the

```
wine-openal.i686 : Openal support for wine
wine-openal.x86_64 : Openal support for wine
```

why??

I tryied to yum remove wine*..ok it removed all the wine* packages from my system, but... when I tried to yum install wine... the same error message with "Requires: libopenal.so.1"...came up..

I tried to:

```
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
rpm -vv --rebuilddb
```

but it didn't helped..

```
[root@NOTEBOOK /etc/yum.repos.d] ls
epel.repo           linux_signing_key.pub    mirrors-rpmforge-testing  sl.repo           virtualbox.repo
epel-testing.repo   mirrors-rpmforge         rpmforge.repo             sl.repo;502df2db
google-chrome.repo  mirrors-rpmforge-extras  sl-other.repo             sl.repo;502e1e13
[root@NOTEBOOK /etc/yum.repos.d]
```

I primary use rpmforge, and epel is just this:

```
[root@NOTEBOOK /etc/yum.repos.d] cat epel.repo 
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
includepkgs=nss-mdns wine* gparted cups-pdf
```

Q: How can I resolve this problem?

===============================================

UPDATE: I tried to download the:

```
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15175751/dir/scientific_linux_6/com/openal-soft-1.12.854-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15174245/dir/scientific_linux_6/com/openal-soft-1.12.854-1.el6.i686.rpm.html
```

but it gives "Error 550" ...
...

So... I tried:

```
http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/atrpms-i386/openal-soft-1.12.854-1.el6.i686.rpm/download/
http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/epel-x86_64/openal-soft-1.12.854-1.el6.x86_64.rpm/download/
```

"rpm -i"-ed the two rpm packages (these packages provided the libopenal.so.1's..), then:

```
[root@NOTEBOOK /etc/yum.repos.d] yum install wine
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.pmf.kg.ac.rs
 * rpmforge: ftp.lug.ro
 * sl: ftp1.scientificlinux.org
 * sl-security: ftp1.scientificlinux.org
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package wine.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: wine-wow(x86-64) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-twain(x86-64) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-twain(x86-32) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-pulseaudio(x86-64) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-pulseaudio(x86-32) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-openal(x86-64) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-openal(x86-32) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-ldap(x86-64) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-ldap(x86-32) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-fonts = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-desktop = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-core(x86-64) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-core(x86-32) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-cms(x86-64) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-cms(x86-32) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-capi(x86-64) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: wine-capi(x86-32) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package wine-capi.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-capi.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-cms.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-cms.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-core.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: wine-common = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 for package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgstbase-0.10.so.0 for package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgstapp-0.10.so.0 for package: wine-core-1.4.1-1.el6.i686
---> Package wine-core.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-desktop.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: wine-tahoma-fonts = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-fonts-1.4.1-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: wine-system-fonts = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-fonts-1.4.1-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: wine-symbol-fonts = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-fonts-1.4.1-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: wine-small-fonts = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-fonts-1.4.1-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: wine-ms-sans-serif-fonts = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-fonts-1.4.1-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: wine-marlett-fonts = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-fonts-1.4.1-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: wine-courier-fonts = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-fonts-1.4.1-1.el6.noarch
---> Package wine-ldap.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-ldap.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-openal.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-openal.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-pulseaudio.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: wine-alsa(x86-32) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-pulseaudio-1.4.1-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: alsa-plugins-pulseaudio(x86-32) for package: wine-pulseaudio-1.4.1-1.el6.i686
---> Package wine-pulseaudio.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: wine-alsa(x86-64) = 1.4.1-1.el6 for package: wine-pulseaudio-1.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package wine-twain.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-twain.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-wow.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package alsa-plugins-pulseaudio.i686 0:1.0.21-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package gstreamer.i686 0:0.10.29-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package gstreamer-plugins-base.i686 0:0.10.29-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtheoraenc.so.1(libtheoraenc_1.0) for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcdda_interface.so.0 for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: liboil-0.3.so.0 for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libtheoradec.so.1(libtheoradec_1.0) for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libvisual-0.4.so.0 for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcdda_paranoia.so.0 for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libtheoradec.so.1 for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgudev-1.0.so.0 for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libtheoraenc.so.1 for package: gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.29-1.el6.i686
---> Package wine-alsa.i686 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-alsa.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-common.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-courier-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-marlett-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-ms-sans-serif-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-small-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-symbol-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-system-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package wine-tahoma-fonts.noarch 0:1.4.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cdparanoia-libs.i686 0:10.2-5.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libgudev1.i686 0:147-2.40.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libudev = 147-2.40.el6 for package: libgudev1-147-2.40.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libudev.so.0 for package: libgudev1-147-2.40.el6.i686
---> Package liboil.i686 0:0.3.16-4.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libtheora.i686 1:1.1.0-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package libvisual.i686 0:0.4.0-9.1.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libudev.i686 0:147-2.40.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Protected multilib versions: libudev-147-2.40.el6.i686 != libudev-147-2.41.el6.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: libgudev1-147-2.40.el6.i686 != libgudev1-147-2.41.el6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@NOTEBOOK /etc/yum.repos.d] 
[root@NOTEBOOK /etc/yum.repos.d] rpm -qa | grep -i libudev
libudev-147-2.41.el6.x86_64
[root@NOTEBOOK /etc/yum.repos.d]
```

...so now I got a:

Error: Protected multilib versions: libudev-147-2.40.el6.i686 != libudev-147-2.41.el6.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: libgudev1-147-2.40.el6.i686 != libgudev1-147-2.41.el6.x86_64

error message... what to do next?? how can I fix this??

Comment: plz somebody help :)

Comment: Why is your libgudev protected?

Comment: I don't know, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK fully enabling epel repo (commenting: includepkgs=nss-mdns wine* gparted cups-pdf) solves the problem.